# How to display different tooltip formats in series of data in High Chart

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

Here I have a series of data while some of the series having time duration like `00:12:00` and other having an `int` value,

Here is my Javascript code (you can also view it on [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tank_hit/efgu7eru/)):

```
$(function () {
$('#container').highcharts({
    chart: {
        type: 'line',
        inverted: false
    },
    title: {
        text: 'Duration Data'
    },
    xAxis: {
        categories: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun',
            'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec']

    },
    yAxis: {
        min: 0,
        type: "datetime",
        title: {
            text: 'Time Duration'
        },
        lineWidth: 2,
        labels: {
            formatter: function () {
                var ts = this.value,
                    hs = ts / (3600 * 1000),
                    ms = new Date(ts).getUTCMinutes();
                    sc = new Date(ts).getUTCSeconds();

                sc = sc < 10 ? '0' + sc : sc;
                ms = ms < 10 ? '0' + ms : ms;

                hs = hs < 10 ? '0' + hs : hs;

                if(hs > 1)
                    return hs + ":" + ms +":" + sc;
                else
                    return ms +":" + sc;
            }
        }
    },
    tooltip:{
        formatter:function() {
            return Highcharts.dateFormat('%H:%M:%S',this.y);
        }
    },
    legend: {
        enabled: false
    },

    plotOptions: {
        spline: {
            marker: {
                enable: false
            }
        }
    },
    series: [{
        name: 'Time',
        data: [600000, 2520000,75610000]
    },
    {
        name: 'Price',
        data: [12,778,123]
    }]
});
});
```

Here is my HTML code:

```
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>
<div id="container" style="min-width: 310px; height: 400px; max-width:        600px; margin: 0 auto"></div>
```

How can I differentiate multiple series data in High Chart?

Comment: You can check name of serie and then return correct tooltip content.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
tooltip:{
            formatter:function() {
               var a = Highcharts.dateFormat('%H:%M:%S',this.y);
                if(a === "00:00:00"){
                  return this.y;
                }else{
                  return a;
                }
            }
        }
```

Here Is the updated fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/ishandemon/efgu7eru/2/

Updated fiddle with series name: http://jsfiddle.net/ishandemon/efgu7eru/3/

Comment: thank you for giving answer is there possible to display name of `y-axis `label name ? for example `Time Duration`  ?

Comment: Yes you can get it by using `this.series.name`